# Custom View in android/

Tags: android, android-widget

I need to make a custom view as shown in diagram, which needs to functional like radio button, any of the options needs to be selected. How can I achieve this? I don`t want to use series of buttons.

[image]

Comment: I think, you can start from here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html

Comment: Try TabHost..You can see example of tabhost [here](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-tabhost-tutorial-part-1/)...

Answer (score 0):

You can use RadioGroup and RadioButtons to achieve this. For example,

```
<RadioButton 
android:id="@+id/custom_btn"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="1"
android:button="@null"
android:background="@drawable/button_custom"/>
```

Where button_custom is the background image of the button shown. This image should have all the variations (like, normal, pressed, enabled, disabled, selected).